# Saving ObservableCollection to file (.txt)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, save, observablecollection

Whats the best way for me to save an observableCollection of data that I have displayed in a listview to a file(.txt). I had it working when I didnt have the observableCollection and the binding data shown below, for this i simply used a string builder. From the code below how can i save the "Process name"

XAML code

```xml
<ListView Height="146"  ScrollBar.Scroll="listView1_Scroll" ItemsSource="{Binding StatisticsCollection}">   <ListView.View>
   <GridView >
      <GridViewColumn Header="Process Name" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ProcessName}" />
   </GridView>
</Listview.View>
```

Stringbuilder that use to work

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
foreach (object item in listView1.Items)
{
    sb.AppendLine(item.ToString());
}
```

Declaration

```
 ObservableCollection<StatisticsData> _StatisticsCollection =
    new ObservableCollection<StatisticsData>();

    public ObservableCollection<StatisticsData> StatisticsCollection
    {
        get { return _StatisticsCollection; }
    }
```

Any feedback would be great,

Thanks

Martin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do a similar `foreach` loop for your ObservableCollection.

```
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    foreach (StatisticsData item in StatisticsCollection)
    {

        sb.AppendLine(item.ToString());

    }
```

Comment: the output i get when opened is 'MemoryMonitor.MainWindow+StatisticsData'.

Comment: @carsey88 instead of `item.ToString()` try `item.ProcessName` if that's the property from each item you want written to the file.

Comment: used item.ProcessName.Tostring(). Thanks very much, was driving me insane

Answer (score 1):

From your naming of "_StatisticsCollection" I am assuming you save it as a field variable? If so, just iterate that instead, and write the "ProcessName" property to the file/StringBuilder. Alternatively, use the Linq.Enumerable extension method "Cast" to iterate the items as "StatisticsData" : foreach (var item in listView1.Items.Cast). Again, it is the property "ProcessName" you would want to write out.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use any temp variables, it is unnecessary. Write directly to file:

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("text.txt"))
{
    foreach (StatisticsData item in StatisticsCollection)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(item.ToString());
    }
}
```